# Add Target for x amount of buttons and going back to tabBarController

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

This is my code so far:

```
    func getFriends() {
        let numOfFriends = userDefaults.integer(forKey: "numOfFriends")
        if numOfFriends > 0{
            //Show friend Labels
            let friendNames = userDefaults.array(forKey: "friendNames") as! Array<String>
            for x in 0...friendNames.count - 1 {
                let button = UIButton()
                button.setTitle(friendNames[x], for: .normal)
                button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
                button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.tapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
            }
            checkFriends()
        }
        else{
            // show a label syaing no friends
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = "You have no friends :("
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
            checkFriends()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func tapped(_ sender: UIButton){
        if sender.currentTitle != nil {
            //Set active friend
            userDefaults.set(sender.currentTitle, forKey: "currentFriend")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
            //Go to FriendInfoViewController
        }
    }
```

So when `getFriends()` is called it creates `friendNames.count` amount of buttons. I want all of these buttons to go to another view controller called `FriendInfoViewController`. The current ViewController is connected to a Navigation Controller and that is connected to a TabBarController.

The problem that I am facing is how to go to that next view controller and then go back and it still be in the TabBarController

Comment: I'm not sure thats the best structure for your ViewControllers. Have you tried TabBarController and every ViewController embedded in it's own Navigation controller. I can Provide and example if required.

Comment: @latenitecoder Thats what I said I had done in the question. Sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: Like I said I can knock up a small project and share it with you if you want a working example. It's way to difficult to go into detail here on a webpage. Let me know, will take about 5 minutes to make.

Comment: Please could you do that

Comment: No Problem - so the requirement is tabbar screen that moves to a view controller with the tab bar not showing but navigates back to the tab bar screen?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about setting up the storyboard and view controllers to behave the way you are asking for.

The storyboard

This consists of a Tab Bar Controller as the root view controller, containing two tabs which are linked to view controllers. Xcode provides these two by default when creating a tab bar controller.

For both tabs' view controllers I embededded them both in their own navigation controllers. You do this by selecing the View Controller in interface builder, then from the Xcode menu select Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller.
This gives us the ability to add and navigate to as many view controllers we like for each tab independently.

[image]

For both view controllers, create view controller subclasses, I named mine Tab1ViewController and Tab2ViewController, and remember to change the Class setting in Xcode's Identity Inspector to match for each.

[image]

The original question asked how to pass data to a new view controller, and have the ability to navigate back. This can be achieved many way, through Segues is an option but, I prefer to do mine manually for visibilty.

So assuming the array containg the data to pass, is filled, we pass it to FriendInfoViewController, which is the view we want to navigate to,  when we reference it from the storyboard

The code:

```
class Tab1ViewController: UIViewController {

    var friendNames: [String] = [] // array for holding the data that needs to be passed
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func getFriends(_ sender: Any) {

        self.friendNames = ["David", "Sally", "Pete", "Michael", "Chris"] // populate the array with data

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil) // create a reference to the storyboard
        let friendInfoViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FriendInfoViewController") as! FriendInfoViewController // instantiate an instance of the viewcontroller we want to navigate to
        
        // populate the matching array in the new view controller with the array containing the data we wish to pass
        friendInfoViewController.friendNames = self.friendNames 

        // create a reference to the navigation controller connected to the viewcontroller we are currently in
        guard let currentNavController = tabBarController?.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController  else {
            fatalError("Failed to detect navigation controller.")
        }
        
        // display the newly created view controller
        currentNavController.pushViewController(friendInfoViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Tab2ViewController was created as an exact copy, the only difference is when FriendInfoViewController is displayed, the Tab Bar is hidden.
To make that happen programatically you add this.

```
friendInfoViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true // Here is how you hide the tabs
```

And for completeness, FriendInfoViewController looks like this. Notice we have the friendNames array, which is the array that receives the data from either Tab1ViewController or Tab2ViewController. The other thing to note is the inclusion of a button that is linked to an action which asks the navigation controller to remove FriendInfoViewController (itself) and animate back to the rootview, showing the tabs and their respective view controllers.

```
class FriendInfoViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var friendNames: [String] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(friendNames) // note you have access to friendNames anywhere in the class 
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func goBackAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here is a link to the example I created as a project

[Tabbar Navigation Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BLehaEn4VmgLFRcqtktSvD3NDWeqQyOQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This might be useful to the OP but an answer consisting of nothing but a link is not an answer. Please provide actual code here, or at least an explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Fair point - will update the answer to show how it all works.